# Ignoring sublist in css

Tags: html, css

So I am trying myself in html and css3 and I found a problem described in pictures:

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEShZ.png)

[image]

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b8WK.png)

[image]
So what I want to do is to ignore that the textfield of "Concepts" shifts "Planets" to the right.

This is how the html structure looks like at the moment:

HTML:

```
 <div class="masthead__inner-wrap">
   <li class="masthead_menu-item">
   <a href="LinkToConcepts"></a> 
     <ul subhead-links>
       <li class="subhead-link">
         <a href="LinkToSubheadLink"></a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.masthead__menu-item {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;

  &--lg {
    padding-right: 2em;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
}

.subhead-links{
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  border-color: $border-color;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;

  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
}

.subhead-link {
  font-size: $type-size-7;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;

  &--lg {
    padding-right: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
}
```

So what I do is fill the subhead links in as listitems (via liquid) and then display them as subhead-links.
But I do not know how to ignore the "subhead" listitems so that the next masthead__menu-item is not shifted.

Thank you!

Comment: please add you css to the post

Comment: your words are confusing.... What should happen when some one click 'Concepts' or 'Planets'?  Also you need to update your html with at least link names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```css
.masthead_menu-item li{display:inline;}
.sublist li{display:none;}
.sublist:target li{
 display:inline;
 }
```

```html
<div class="masthead__inner-wrap">
    <ul class="masthead_menu-item">
        <li><a href="#concepts_sublist">Concepts</a></li>
  <li><a href="#planets_sublist">Planets</a></li>
    </ul>
 <ul class="sublist" id="concepts_sublist">
  <li><a href="#">Waves</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Magic</a></li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="sublist" id="planets_sublist">
  <li><a href="#">Planet1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Planet2</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is what I searched for!

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to target the direct descendent (not all children) then use the (child selector)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors]

For example:

```
.masthead_menu-item > a {
    color: green; /* Will not affect <li><a>...</a></li> */
}
```

However, I get the feeling that's not what you're really asking.  The HTML you've posted doesn't really mirror your before/after graphics.

For a more specific answer, please post your markup and CSS

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is more that if I add items to the subhead the textfield of subhead-links gets filled and through that shifts the Masthead-menu-items. So what I want is listing the subhead links without shifting the masthead items